# Convert string into an object using reduce javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, reduce

I am trying to convert a string like "sheep" into an object like this:

```
{
   "s":{
      "initial":1,
      "final":1
   },
   "h":{
      "initial":1,
      "final":1
   },
   "e":{
      "initial":2,
      "final":2
   },
   "p":{
      "initial":1,
      "final":1
   }
}
```

Currently I can use reduce method in javascript and achive this:

```
const names = 'sheep'.split('');
const count = (names) =>
  names.reduce((acc, name) => ({ ...acc, [name]: (acc[name] || 0) + 1 }), {});
console.log(count(names)) //{ s: 1, h: 1, e: 2, p: 1 }
```

I have tried to read similar posts but I am pretty new to JS. Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: You are already pretty close, you just need to define the desired structure inside the reduce callback, but it is not clear what is the difference between `initial` and `final`values. Can you elaborate on those?

Comment: I am going to modify the final count for my specific purpose. Sorry for using a simple example  But the question has been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```js
const names = "sheep".split("");
const count = (names) =>
  names.reduce(
    (acc, name) => ({
      ...acc,
      [name]: {
        initial: (acc?.[name]?.initial ?? 0) + 1,
        final: (acc?.[name]?.final ?? 0) + 1,
      },
    }),
    {}
  );
console.log(count(names));
```

Answer (score 2):

This works printing your desired output but I'm not sure why you want the initial and final counts to be the same

```
const letters = 'sheep'.split('');
const count = (letters) =>
  letters.reduce((obj, letter) => ({ ...obj, [letter]: {initial: (obj[letter]?.initial || 0) + 1, final: (obj[letter]?.final || 0) + 1} }), {});
console.log(count(letters))
```

Alternatively, you could expand a function there using braces and do some if's in order to have the code more readable instead of the ternaries

Comment: I am going to modify the final count for my specific purpose. Sorry for using a simple example 